# Do AWS Lambda logging levels prevent writing of lower level logs, or just hide them?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

I have an AWS Lambda function (.NET 6, if that's relevant) with some logs which are very useful for debugging during development, but which in production would hold information we must not store. I'm hoping that simply setting the logging level environment variable to "Information" in production will stop these logs from ever being written, allowing me to avoid making production-specific code changes.

To give an example, say I have a function with some Log.Debug() statements in it, set the function's logging level to "Information" and then invoke it several times, is there any way to retrieve the Debug logs afterwards (e.g. change logging level back to "Debug")?

Comment: Where exactly would it be "hiding" those logs? In a separate "hidden" log file or something?

Comment: By hidden, I just mean not shown in the CloudWatch logs - I appreciate that its relationship with lambda is meant to be one way, so I'm likely worrying about nothing, just trying to be thorough here.

Comment: CloudWatch logs doesn't know anything about your log configuration level. It just knows what logs were sent to it. CloudWatch doesn't do any sort of "hiding" based on the log level of your application at the time you logged something. That log level literally just tells your application what logs to output, and CloudWatch just stores whatever is output.

Comment: Ok great, that's my understanding as well, really just wanted someone to corroborate.